# SQL Pivot Query Dynamic Columns for Date Ranges Failed

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic, pivot

Can someone tell me what's wrong with this Microsoft SQL? I tried to use SQL Pivot function to for dynamic date columns.

**Results:**
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
Incorrect syntax near ';'.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '2023-02-01';
DECLARE @EndDate DATE = '2023-02-05';

DECLARE @ColumnList AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

DECLARE @sql     NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';
-- populate column list 

WITH DateRange(DateData) AS 
(
    SELECT @StartDate as Date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,DateData)
    FROM DateRange 
    WHERE DateData < @EndDate
)
SELECT @ColumnList = ISNULL(@ColumnList + ',', '')
        + QUOTENAME(DateData)
FROM DateRange
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 300);


-- construct dynamic SQL
SET @sql ='
SELECT * FROM   
(
  Select * from 
  (
  SELECT [Trade Date], [Market Participant] AS [Member], [sides] as [Volume]
  FROM [RMH].[dbo].[R3_Trades_TO_new]
  WHERE [Trade Origin description]=''AAA''
  and [Trade Date]>=''2023-02-01'' and [Trade Date]<=''2023-02-05''
) t 
PIVOT(
    COUNT([Volume]) 
    FOR [Trade Date] IN ('+ @ColumnList +')
) AS pivot_table;';

-- execute the dynamic SQL
EXECUTE  sp_executesql @sql;
```

I want the results to show dynamic dates as columns '2023-02-01' '2023-02-02' '2023-02-03' etc

Comment: Line 14 - which one is that?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing part of the query:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '2023-02-01';
DECLARE @EndDate DATE = '2023-02-05';

DECLARE @ColumnList AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

DECLARE @sql     NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';
-- populate column list 

WITH DateRange(DateData) AS 
(
    SELECT @StartDate as Date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,DateData)
    FROM DateRange 
    WHERE DateData < @EndDate
)
SELECT @ColumnList = ISNULL(@ColumnList + ',', '')
        + QUOTENAME(DateData)
FROM DateRange
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 300);


-- construct dynamic SQL
SET @sql ='
SELECT * FROM   
(
  Select * from 
  (
      SELECT [Trade Date], [Market Participant] AS [Member], [sides] as [Volume]
      FROM [RMH].[dbo].[R3_Trades_TO_new]
      WHERE [Trade Origin description]=''AAA''
      and [Trade Date]>=''2023-02-01'' and [Trade Date]<=''2023-02-05''
    ) t 
) DS
PIVOT(
    COUNT([Volume]) 
    FOR [Trade Date] IN ('+ @ColumnList +')
) AS pivot_table;';

SELECT @sql



-- execute the dynamic SQL
EXECUTE  sp_executesql @sql;
```

This one here:

[image]

Which is actually not needed (you have one sub-query more). It can be only:

```
-- construct dynamic SQL
SET @sql ='
SELECT * 
FROM   
(

    SELECT [Trade Date], [Market Participant] AS [Member], [sides] as [Volume]
    FROM [RMH].[dbo].[R3_Trades_TO_new]
    WHERE [Trade Origin description]=''AAA''
    and [Trade Date]>=''2023-02-01'' and [Trade Date]<=''2023-02-05''

) DS
PIVOT(
    COUNT([Volume]) 
    FOR [Trade Date] IN ('+ @ColumnList +')
) AS pivot_table;';

SELECT @sql
```

Comment: Thanks very much, gotqn. I am a SQL starter. How can I put the StartDate and EndDate variables inside the Pivot SQL to replace the hard code text?